# Molecular propellant in ion engines

Tags: fuel, ion-thruster, chemistry

This question was prompted by discussions on [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34479/12102). Can there be an advantage to using a molecular propellant in an ion engine, as opposed to noble gasses or iodine? (Although iodine actually does look pretty cool.) There's a large variety of molecules to choose from, but it seems like you could find some that are cheap, heavy, easy to ionize, and store well.

I can think of a disadvantage, which is dissociation. Like the quench gas in a GM tube, except quench gasses are specifically chosen for that property.

Comment: See also [Why is Xenon favored as the propellant in electric thrusters?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/161819/why-is-xenon-favored-as-the-propellant-in-electric-thrusters)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a little bit of an answer. One possibility is carbon-60, or "buckyballs".
https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=5698
But that article is from 1991, so if it hasn't caught on by now, it probably won't.

Another alternative is air--whatever happens to be in it. That is being developed by the ESA. But for the availability of it, not for advantageous material properties. 
https://futurism.com/esa-ion-thruster-breathes-air

In general, when they talk about alternatives to xenon, they usually mean krypton, argon, iodine, or sometimes hydrogen. Molecular propellants don't seem to be a hot topic. But it seems worth looking at.

Comment: `+1` The 1990's were *the decade of the buckyball", then carbon nanotubes in 2000's and graphene in 2010's. People were proposing these as the solution to everything. Many things didn't catch on. ;-)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHwGM.png see also Physics ArXiv Blog: [Algorithm Distinguishes Memes from Ordinary Information](https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/algorithm-distinguishes-memes-from-ordinary-information-af86a6edfa5b)