# Why was circa 600 volts used for DAWN's ion propulsion?

Tags: engine-design, mission-design, ion-thruster, dawn-mission

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43433/12102) estimates that the [DAWN spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_(spacecraft))'s solar-electric propulsion accelerated about 3 milligrams of Xe<sup>+1</sup> per second, using roughly 1350 Watts of electrical power. I estimate that 3 mg/sec of Xe<sup>+1</sup> should be about 2.2 amps, so the acceleration potential might be in the ballpark of 600 volts.

Is the choice of voltages near 1 kilovolt the result of some optimization in kinematics? If so, can it be explained quantitatively with a simple mathematical model? Would say 200 or 2000 volts have both resulted in poorer use of the available

1. solar-electric power?
2. propellant?
3. time?

Comment: potentially helpful [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43411/12102) and there good information in this paper about DAWN's engine progenitor: [Performance of the NSTAR ion propulsion system on the Deep Space One mission](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3868954_Performance_of_the_NSTAR_ion_propulsion_system_on_the_Deep_Space_One_mission) that may be helpful as well.

Comment: You might want to change your estimations to the actual numbers you found in the paper you linked: 1100V, 1.76A, 23.43sccm

Comment: @asdfex ya I've just used the results of the previous answer to make an estimate for DAWN, and the paper I mentioned in the *comment* is for NSTAR.

Comment: Dawn used NSTAR engines.

Comment: @asdfex If you'd like to assert that a voltage from a paper from 2000 about Deep Space 1 is the same as a voltage used on the DAWN spacecraft launched 7 years later, consider writing it up as part of an answer rather than trying to get me to assert it in a question?

Comment: With limited power high voltage means low current, low particle flow, and mass flow, and low thrust, unless you switch to a heavier particle.

Comment: @asdfex so far I've only found [The Dawn spacecraft was propelled by three xenon ion thrusters **derived from NSTAR technology** used by the Deep Space 1 spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_(spacecraft)#Propulsion_system) The way this is written suggest to me that Dawn's engines are not necessarily exactly the same as the NSTAR engine used by DS-1 and operated in exactly the same way.

Comment: "The ion thrusters for Dawn are identical to the DSI flight thrusters.". Brophy et al. in The ion propulsion system for DAWN, 2013

Comment: @asdfex okay I've found it, thanks! https://www.researchgate.net/publication/239923134_The_Ion_Propulsion_System_for_Dawn

Comment: Being a transit geek, I can't help noticing that 600v is commonly used for streetcars and subways, so perhaps there are many components that would be considered COTS, or it's just familiar tech.